# How to coordinate test across multiple scrum teams

Tags: testing, agile, scrum

I am involved in a new project that is using scrum and has scaled from one scrum team to four and will probably grow further. It's a new technology so the architecture is still evolving, so the pieceparts need to be system tested as a whole. Using the car analogy we have teams for chassis, brakes, engine, and steering. Any given story has a focus (eg faster acceleration) and is assigned to one team (eg engine). The definition of done usually defines criteria wrt that piece in that scrum. However some testing still needs to be done of the 'system' (eg drive the car around the track) to make sure changes didn't break other parts of the system. Eg the engine may be heavier which affected the braking or steering.

[Here](http://thescrumblog.blogspot.com/2011/05/scaling-scrum-done.html) points out that a separate test team is NOT the answer. It lists 'separate test team' first in their 'top five issues when scaling scrum'. So the 'system' testing must be handled with the scrum structure.

Should the definition of done (which drives the test criteria) include the entire system (so all teams do full regression test of all areas) or just their focus area (eg the brake team's regression test of some other story is what discovers the impact the changed engine had). There seems to be a tradeoff between duplication and coverage. We would like to avoid scrumfall (eg adding another 'stage' of testing), avoid duplication, yet still discover issues as quickly and 'close to source' as possible.

How does system test scale as a project grows to multiple scrum teams?

Comment: I'm confused as to what system tests have to do with Scrum?

Comment: @DaveHillier - when we were one scrum team, our scrum team included test. Now that we are four scrum teams, test is still part of each scrum team but it is less clear who is responsible for overall system test.

Comment: your "system test" sounds like a waterfall stage, not a Scrum concept. Use a [definition of done](http://www.scrumalliance.org/articles/105-what-is-definition-of-done-dod) to decide what testing is required before a story is considered complete.

Comment: @DaveHillier - I edited question to hopefully better explain the problem. It's 'scrumfall' I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Are your teams using continuous integration at all?

Comment: What is the point in having separate teams? Why not just have one big one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 4):

In agile development, *avoid dependencies like the plague*.

It seems to me that *none of the four teams is producing value* by itself. This is the biggest problem you need to address.

If a team is *not* producing value, what does *done* mean? How do you prioritize when you need teams to sync up in order to get a car done?

Compare how Facebook works (for example, and as far as I know):

- One team is does the chat
- One team does the photo albums
- One tem does the timeline
- ecc...

They all deploy - i.e. directly generate value - and are completely independent in their testing.

If your teams are producing value, then *by definition* there is no need of cross-team system testing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is, that your DOD does not include the Integration Test.

If you extend the DOD to this stage, all 4 teams will integrate there results early - during the sprint - to an integration stage and get results from there.
It is important to do this early in the sprint, because otherwise bugs from this stage will be to late for fixing in the same sprint. However fixing bugs in the sprint they where identified is a must have. Buggy code is not DONE.

Extending the DOD to another stage is also a best practice for teams that fulfill there DOD regularly anyway.

BTW: Extending the DOD will of course affect your velocity in the beginning. This is normal, because you will do more to fulfill the DOD.